# Uncaught Error: process.binding is not supported (browserify+selenium-webdriver)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserify

I am trying to run a node js code in my browser i.e. client side. I am using browserify to convert my code to browser compatible code. My code below uses selenium web-driver and cheerio. I use this command to convert it

> > browserify test.js -o btest.js

My code looks like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();


function getdata(email,username,password,callBack,errCallBack){

var url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/'+username;
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/');
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="login-email"]')).sendKeys(email);
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="login-password"]')).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="login-submit"]')).click();

driver.get(url);
attr={};
driver.findElement(By.className('profile-view-grid')).getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function(profile) { 
    var $= cheerio.load(profile);
    attr['ResearchInterest']=$('h2.pv-top-card-section__headline').text().trim();
});

callBack(attr);


}
```

When I include the btest.js in my html code and try to run it I get the error:

```
 Uncaught Error: process.binding is not supported
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getdata is not defined
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Is it that my conversion using browserify is incorrect or if selenium web driver cannot run in the browser using browserify? If so what are my options. Any helpful article or blogpost having similar examples is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run webdriver test code in the browser ... which will attempt to launch an external process (being the webdriver executable) so you can't do this in a browser.
The error you are seeing arises because browserify isn't just a bundler, it transforms your node code so that it can run in a browser - it provides it's own versions are various builtins - such as buffer, console, etc ... and process. The Browserify version of process consists of just process.nextTick().